# Decoding unknown Format

Tags: node.js, text, encoding, character-encoding, escaping

setup: Nodejs server gets data from pc com port

While reading data on pc serial com port i received following text stream: 
**[13;27HF [13;27H [1mF [22m [27m [13;31H44 [13;31H [1m44  [22m [27m [13;37H       [22m [27m [13;37H [13;46HPTORDR [13;46H [1mPTORDR [22m [27m [13;55HCR [13;55H [1mCR   [22m [27m [13;62HF419152 [13;62H [1mF419152    [22m [27m [13;75HSL [13;75H [1mSL [22m [27m [24;00H [2K%CHANGE_CLASS, Change of class - Endorsement required [22m [27m**

Is it possible to encode/decode this message?

Answer (score 1):

Those are ANSI escape codes. You may be able to use [node-ansiparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ansiparser).